# Soma de matrizes em java matriz A+ matrizB, resulta na matriz C

Tags: java

Preciso fazer uma algoritmo de soma de matrizes em Java, em que a soma da matrizA com a matrizB, gere a matrizC.
isso se a matrizA tenha o mesmo numero de linhas e colunas que a matriz B.

> Calcule e mostre uma matriz resultante C da soma da matriz A com a matriz B. Só e possível somar a matrizes se elas forem de mesma ordem.

Eu realmente não tenho ideia de como montar essa matrizC, segue o código que consegui até agora.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int N = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o numero de linhas da A"));
    int M = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o numero de colunas da A"));
    int O = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o numero de linhas da B"));
    int P = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o numero de colunas da B"));

    int matrizA[][] = new int[N][M];
    int matrizB[][] = new int[O][P];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrizA.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrizA.length; j++) {

            matrizA[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o " + (i + 1) + " valor da matriz A"));

        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < matrizB.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrizB.length; j++) {

            matrizB[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o " + (j + 1) + " valor da matriz B"));
        }

    }

    int soma = 0;

    if (N == O && M == P) {

        for (int i = 0; i < matrizB.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrizB.length; j++) {

                soma = matrizA[i][j] + matrizB[i][j];

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Falta declarar a `matrizC` com o tamanho de uma das outras e usa-la no sitio onde está a `soma = ...`, para que fique `matrizC[i][j] = ...`

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado !

Answer (score -1):

No lugar desse int soma, crie a matrizC direto e atribua os valores.

```
int[][] matrizC;

if (N == O && M == P) {

    for (int i = 0; i < matrizB.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrizB.length; j++) {

            matrizC[i][j] = matrizA[i][j] + matrizB[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```